# setState is no a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I made a custom hook that changes background colors so when I invoke the `setStatus` on anohter file I get `setStatus` is not a function..

```js
export const useTheme = ({ backGround, fontColor }: themeProps) => {
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState<string>("");
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState<string>(" ");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (status === "pending") {
        setBgColor("#F2F2F2");
        setTextColor("#666666");
      }
      if (status === "Rejceted") {
        setBgColor("#E23525");
        setTextColor("#E23525");
      }
      if (status === "Approved") {
        setBgColor("#E8FDF3");
        setTextColor("#12B76A");
      }
    };
  }, [status, backGround, fontColor]);
  return { bgColor, textColor, setBgColor, setTextColor, setStatus };
};
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

The useEffect syntax you have used is incorrect. You have added the logic within the return which will be used to clear things when being unmounted. please find an example below which is working

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-perlman-ho767o?file=/src/App.tsx